# How can I copy one section of text from Word to Excel using an Excel macro?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, excel-2007

I need to copy a specific item of text (one or a few words) from Word (2007) to Excel (2007) using an Excel macro, for multiple documents.

So far I have the Excel macro opening each Word document one at a time and locating the text adjacent to what I need.

I now need to:

1. Move to an adjacent cell in a Word table. I'm thinking `wdApp.Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCell` (or `MoveRight`) where wdApp is `Word.Application`
2. Copy the contents of the cell. I'm thinking `wdApp.Selection.Copy` and something like `wdDoc.Word.Range` where `wdDoc` is `Word.Document` but I can't select the whole cells contents.
3. Paste it into a variable in Excel. Here I don't know how to copy the clipboard to an Excel variable.

Comment: Do you need to copy and paste?  Why not just use Selection.Text ?

Comment: @Tim - thx. I'm still having trouble getting the selection into the clipboard... but that may work for step 3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Updated to show searching for text and then selecting content relative to its location:

```
Sub FindAndCopyNext()

    Dim TextToFind As String, TheContent As String
    Dim rng As Word.Range

    TextToFind = "wibble" 'the text you're looking for to
                          ' locate the other content

    Set rng = wdApp.ActiveDocument.Content
    rng.Find.Execute FindText:=TextToFind, Forward:=True

    If rng.Find.Found Then
        If rng.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
          TheContent = rng.Cells(1).Next.Range.Text      'move right on row
          'TheContent = rng.Cells(1).Previous.Range.Text 'move left on row
          MsgBox "Found content '" & TheContent & "'"
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Text '" & TextToFind & "' was not found!"
    End If

End Sub
```

Then assign the variable TheContent to your required Excel range.

Comment: Thanks. But how can I select a certain part of the document? Currently this is not getting anything, because I can't select text. I can use Range(Start:=0, End:=200) to get the first 200 characters.

Comment: Is the text you want to copy always in the same location (same position in a table for example) or in a fixed location relative to some other text?

Comment: the latter. Mostly in the cell directly to the left or right. Occasionally in another cell but always in the same row. So I'll need to verify the string.

Comment: Updated my answer to include searching for text to locate the content