# File path of links in Word Document

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I'm working on excel vba, I just want to access a word document, and list the file path of all the links within it. ie. "c:\excelfile.xls"

Comment: I need the file links/data links. Not hyperlinks. Linked documents. I need a list of all the data sources. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your document is open, try this:

```
Sub due()
    Dim msWord As Object
    Dim msDoc As Object
    Dim msHlink As Object

    Set msWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    Set msDoc = msWord.Documents(1) 'change to suit

    For Each msHlink In msDoc.Hyperlinks
        Debug.Print msHlink.Address
    Next
End Sub
```

Word same as Excel have [Hyperlinks Collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff192421(v=office.14).aspx) where you can access all available hyperlinks on the document.

**Edit1:** To get embedded *Excel Object Links* you need to access the *InlineShapes Collection*.
Something like:

```
Sub due()
    Dim msWord As Word.Application
    Dim msDoc As Word.Document
    Dim iShp As Word.InlineShape

    Set msWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    Set msDoc = msWord.Documents(1) 'change to suit

    For Each iShp In msDoc.InlineShapes
        Debug.Print iShp.LinkFormat.SourceFullName
    Next
End Sub
```

To get all the available properties for *[InlineShape object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/aa221989(v=office.12))*, make sure to add reference to *Microsoft Word XX.0 Object Library*. Take note that I used *Early Binding* above. HTH.

Comment: Do you have the ones for file/data links? Not the hyperlinks. ie I've attached tables from excel files into the word doc... I need a list of all the excel files I linked the document with.

Comment: @gemmo Yes sure. When you said links in your question, the first thing that comes to my mind are *hyperlinks*. But yes, you can access those objects as well. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this:

```
Sub OpenWordDocument()

    dim Word as Object
    Set Word = CreateObject("word.Application")

    Word.documents.Open "C:\excelfile.xls"

    Word.Visible = True

End Sub
```

for the copying you could check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7338385/how-can-i-copy-one-section-of-text-from-word-to-excel-using-an-excel-macro)