# Copy Text After Found Text from Word to Excel

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

So I have been using code from [How can I copy one section of text from Word to Excel using an Excel macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7338385/how-can-i-copy-one-section-of-text-from-word-to-excel-using-an-excel-macro) to copy certain found text into Word.  However, I now need to copy text for a certain number of characters AFTER the found string.  Here is the code so far:

```
Sub FindAndCopyNext()

    Dim TextToFind As String, TheContent As String
    Dim rng As Word.Range

    TextToFind = "Delivery has failed" 'Not sure if this is best string option

    Set rng = wdApp.ActiveDocument.Content
    rng.Find.Execute FindText:=TextToFind, Forward:=True

    If rng.Find.Found Then
        'Need to return text (TheContent) that follow the found text
        LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Range("A" & LastRow).Value = TheContent
    Else
        MsgBox "Text '" & TextToFind & "' was not found!"
    End If

End Sub
```

The text in the Word document always looks like this:

```
'Jibberish Code
<p><b><font color="#000066" size="3" face="Arial">Delivery has failed to these recipients or groups:</font></b></p>
<font color="#000000" size="2" face="Tahoma"><p><a href="mailto:last.first@location.company.com">last.first@location.company.com</a><br>
'Jibberish Code
<p><b><font color="#000066" size="3" face="Arial">Delivery has failed to these recipients or groups:</font></b></p>
<font color="#000000" size="2" face="Tahoma"><p><a href="mailto:last.first@location.company.com">last.first@location.company.com</a><br>
'Jibberish Code
<p><b><font color="#000066" size="3" face="Arial">Delivery has failed to these recipients or groups:</font></b></p>
<font color="#000000" size="2" face="Tahoma"><p><a href="mailto:last.first@location.company.com">last.first@location.company.com</a><br>
```

I need just the `last.first@location.company.com`, each time that string is found, to paste into Excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your string always the same format `last.first@location.company.com`, assign the entire content of your document to a string variable, and then use RegEx

```
Sub FindAndCopyNext()
    Dim wordString As String
    wordString = wdApp.ActiveDocument.Content ' assign entire content of word document to string
    Dim rex As New RegExp
    rex.Pattern = ":(\w+\.\w+@\w+\.\w+\.com)" 'Rex pattern with a capturing group for email
    If rex.Test(wordString) Then
        Range("A1").Value = rex.Execute(wordString)(0).Submatches(0)
    End If
End Sub
```

**Edit:**

Updated Subroutine to capture all emails in document

```
Sub FindAndCopyNext()
    Dim wordString As String
    wordString = wdApp.ActiveDocument.Content ' assign entire content of word document to string
    Dim rex As New RegExp
    rex.Pattern = ":(\w+\.\w+@\w+\.\w+\.com)" 'Rex pattern with a capturing group for email
    rex.Global = True ' multisearch
    Dim i As Long: i = 1
    Dim mtch as Object
    If rex.Test(wordString) Then
        For Each mtch In rex.Execute(wordString)
            Range("A" & i).Value = mtch.Submatches(0)
            i = i + 1
        Next mtch
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I've never used a RegEx search, but it appears this will only work for one e-mail.  I would need it to cycle through all e-mails and jump to new line for each (per my code in Q)

Answer (score 1):

This may not be a brilliant solution in terms of ellegance or performance, but it works well and uses the most basic functions (as opposed to RegEx which someone may suggest).

It uses `InStr` function to find the starting and closing  tags and a `Mid` function to get the string between them.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim str As String
    Dim a1 As Integer
    Dim a2 As Integer

    str = "<p><b><font color=""#000066"" size=""3"" face=""Arial"">Delivery has failed to these recipients or groups:</font></b></p>" & _
          "<font color=""#000000"" size=""2"" face=""Tahoma""><p><a href=""mailto:last.first@location.company.com"">last.first@location.company.com</a><br>"

    a1 = InStr(1, str, "<a href=""mailto:")
    a2 = InStr(a1, str, """>")

    Debug.Print Mid(str, a1 + Len("<a href=""mailto:"), a2 - a1 - Len("<a href=""mailto:"))
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes but the e-mail address is variable. And I need to find the string first.  Just not sure how to find it (possibly a wild card search)

Comment: Yes, this will return the e-mail address from the string, you do not need it before... that's what this is about, isn't it.

Comment: I have to find the string in the Word doc first.  Then your solution becomes valid.

Comment: You get the string by Application.ActiveDocument.Content, as Jeanno suggests. If you have a large string consisting of multiple strings like that, you can parse them into multiple strings into an array and then search per each array item.

Answer (score -2):

cOLUM 1                  COLUM 2                             COLUMN 3
=FIND("Email:",A50)      =MID(A50,B50+6,LEN(A50)-B50+1 )     OUTPUT YOUR EMAIL

hERE A50 is your data with Email:xyz@xyz.com. column B50 is adjacent cell