# Run-time error '1004' while opening Word File

Tags: excel, ms-word, ms-office, vba

I liked the program submitted by @paul bica  in a recent question titled [Search word doc for text and paste into excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32385931/search-word-doc-for-text-and-paste-into-excel-file) and wanted to use for some of my applications. But I am stuck in the beginning itself.

I am getting error `Run-time error '1004'
Method 'GetOpenFilename' of object'_Application' failed.` on the following code line.

```
fName = Application.GetOpenFilename("C\mydir1\aaa.docx")
```

I have applied references to Object Libraries of Microsoft Office 12, Excel 12 and Word 12.
What could go wrong. Further If I strip all other code and  limit the code to simply opening of file, still I am getting the error.

Comment: I'm glad you found it useful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the line `fName = Application.GetOpenFilename("C\mydir1\aaa.docx")`

to this:

```
fName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word Files (*.Doc*),*.Doc*", , _
        "Enter filepath of .doc with desired information")
```

It will show a proper file dialog where you can select your file

After you make your file selection `fName` will be assigned the correct file path and name in your selection (for example `"C\mydir1\aaa.docx"`)